# When using an ordered list, how do I apply a style to ONLY the hovered list item, but not the parent?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/47ZLM/

I attempted to correct it using this:

```
.delete-element-node {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    color: #900;
    float: right;
}

.dd .dd-item:hover > .dd3-content > span.delete-element-node {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

When you hover item 16,17 or 18 - it applies the hover state to the parent also. I want to only apply the style to the currently hovered element.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML code in the question itself. Jsfiddle is just a useful extra, not a replacement for making the question undestandable on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector to

```
.dd .dd-item > .dd3-content:hover > span.delete-element-node {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/47ZLM/1/)</kbd>

It was also shown on the parent element because you were targeting the `.dd-item` which was wrong, you should target the element itself.

---

As you commented, modify your selector to

```
.dd .dd-item > .dd3-content:hover > span.delete-element-node,
.dd .dd-item > .dd-handle.dd3-handle:hover + .dd3-content span.delete-element-node {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/47ZLM/3/)</kbd> *(Will show the `x` on hover of dragger)*

Comment: Cheers - that will work. It would have been nice to account for the drag handle too, but this will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Target the specific li through a class (or id) on the parent.

```
HTML:
<ul class="element-node">
    <li> xxx </li>
</ul>

CSS:
.element-node li {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    color: #900;
    float: right;
}
```

and for the hove target the same li, the same way:

```
CSS:
.element-node li:hover {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```